# Cast Activity Icon not showing in the ActionBar

Tags: android, google-cast

I am writing my first Google Cast application for Android. Going through sender code posted on https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender. The cast button is not showing up in the ActionBar. When I changed the Application ID from the one that google issued to me when I registered the application to the one used in one of the sample applications (I used the one from CastHelloText), then the cast button appeared.

Any ideas what might be the problem? Does it take some time for the newly issued application ID to "propagate" through the system to become "valid"?

Thanks,
Gary

Answer (score 0):

Had to reboot Chromecast device in order for it to sync up with google servers. It's working now.